# What is the function of a capacitor in a motor circuit?

Tags: power, motor

I read a manual of how to connect a speed controller to a motor. I see there is a capacitor as shown below. My question is what the function of the capacitor is? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the manuals?

Comment: http://www.orientalmotor.com/products/pdfs/B_SpdCnt/SpdUs.pdf page B117 and B128 also show the capacitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the speed controller is built to control a three-phase motor from a single phase power line. In short a three phase motor creates a rotating magnetic field in its stator (the part that does not rotate, the housing), and the rotor is dragged along with this rotating field (at a slightly lower rate called 'slip').

To change the direction for a three phase motor, it is sufficient to exchange two of the phases (hence the CW [clockwise] and CCW [counter clockwise] terminals).

The real trick is to create three phases that are about 120° apart and that is where the capacitor comes in. By putting a capacitor in series with one of the windings, the phase angle will be sufficiently shifted to create a rotating magnetic field in the stator and as such you don't need a full three phase controller. Of course the size of the capacitor depends on the current drawn by the motor. Advantage: price of the controller is lower than a full three phase controller; disadvantage: output power of the motor is lower than its three-phase maximum.

[image]

The image and more background information is found [here](http://ijyam.blogspot.nl/2011/06/running-three-phase-ac-induction-motor.html).